# Access to RDS through Databricks with aws certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, databricks, amazon-rds

I am trying to access using spark jdbc to rds instance (mySql) and I am getting the following errors:

```
SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=<rds-host>)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not connect to <rds-host> : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to <rds-host> : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The owner told me that the certificate they use is the global-bundle, so I converted it to jsk and uploaded to databricks dbfs.

I am trying to access again:

```
val reader = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "<jdbc-url>/<database>?useSsl=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=dbfs:/FileStore/tables/rds_ca.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=<password>")
      .option("user", "<username>")
      .option("dbtable","<table>")
      .option("password", "<password>")
      .load()

      reader.show()
```

I am getting same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver does not know how to access DBFS filesystem when you write `dbfs:/FileStore...`.

However DBFS is mounted on driver and all executors at `/dbfs`, so this should work:

```
trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=/dbfs/FileStore/tables/rds_ca.jks
```